# Is '$\alpha$ is regular' (downwards) absolute?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In particular, if $\alpha$ is an initial ordinal, and $\alpha$ is regular in $V$, is $\alpha$ regular in $L$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  If $\alpha$ were singular in $L$, there would be a function $f\in L$ that maps a smaller ordinal onto a cofinal subset of $\alpha$.  The same $f$ would witness that $\alpha$ is singular in $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is downwards absolute.  For a given function $f$, the statement "$f$ is a cofinal function from some ordinal less than $\alpha$ into $\alpha$" is absolute.  The non-existence of such a function is downwards absolute.